# Bash Script to run Davinci with progl

Tags: opencl, amdgpu-pro, davinci-resolve

So I got Davinci Working on Ubuntu 20.04 with my Polaris RX 580, by installing only the OpenCL component of the amdgpu-pro package and as suggested in another post, copying the libgl components of the said driver to a pro/driver folder in my home.

so by adding this;

> progl() {
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/alement/pro/drivers:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
>
> export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH="/home/alements/pro/drivers/dri"
>
> export dri_driver="amdgpu"
>
> }

To my bashrc, I can open a terminal and do "progl && /opt/resolve/bin/resolve" so that the program runs with the pro-OpenGL libs and everything else runs with the normal mesa ones.

So now, only for aesthetics, I want to know if I can create a script to run this from the .desktop DaVinci file instead of having to open the terminal? can I do it?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. We cannot copy that to try and run it, it is harder to read, it cannot be searched and it will cause problems for users with slow connections. Instead, just copy/paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as text.

Comment: Noted and edited.